# How to use tidyverse summarise for median age, if age is in the variable name?

Tags: r, tidyverse, median

Good Evening,

I do have a problem, that I just cannot seem to get around.

Let's assume I'm working with a simplified dataset that looks like this

`library(tidyverse)`

```
data <- tribble(~town , ~patients_aged_17, ~patients_aged_18, ~patients_aged_19, "newyork", 2, 3, 1,"berlin", 1, 1, 4)
```

I would like to use the tidyverse summarise function to calculate the median age for each town.

```
data %>% group_by(town) %>% summarise(median_patient_age = median([problem]))
```

The median for newyork would be `median(c(17, 17, 18, 18, 18, 19)`, so simply using the median function won't yield the desired results.

The question is, how can I get R to calculate the median the correct way ? I guess the answer is quite easy, however I just cant figure it out.

Ps. I can't do it by hand as in the example, as there is way to many groups and "age-variables".

Any hints ?

Best wishes, David.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this will give the desired result

```
library(tidyverse)

data <- tribble(~town , ~patients_aged_17, ~patients_aged_18, ~patients_aged_19, "newyork", 2, 3, 1,"berlin", 1, 1, 4) 

data %>%
  pivot_longer(cols=c(-town), names_to = "age_group", values_to = "count") %>%
  mutate(
    age = as.numeric(gsub("[^\\d]+", "", age_group, perl=TRUE)),
    age_total = count*age 
  ) %>%
  group_by(town) %>%
  summarise(
     count_total = sum(count),
     age_sum = sum(age_total)
  ) %>%
  mutate(
    median_age = age_sum/count_total
  ) %>% 
  select(town, median_age)

# A tibble: 2 x 2
  town    median_age
  <chr>        <dbl>
1 berlin        18.5
2 newyork       17.8
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. However, the results don't match ( i.e. median age for berlin should be 19 for berlin and 18 for new yourk) . However, I think I found a solution; the code however looks kind of ugly `interimdata <- data %>% pivot_longer(cols = -(town), names_to = "age_group", values_to = "count") %>% 
  mutate(age =str_sub(age_group, -2,-1)) %>% 
  group_by(town) %>% 
  summarise(intvar2 = rep(age, count))`

`interimdata$intvar2 <-as.numeric(interimdata$intvar2)` ;

`head(interimdata)` ;

`interimdata %>% group_by(town) %>% summarise(median_age = median(intvar2))`

Comment: Is there a way to nicer format my previous answer? I was constrained by maximum allowed characters (and code does not format as desired)

Comment: You having 19/18 and my answer giving 18.5/17.8 are down to the decimal places. Your answers are rounded to 0 places, mine to 1 decimal place

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I've learned at lot !